# Small caps not appearing on Windows computer

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I've made a document on inDesign CS5 on OSX containing a section typeset in Palatino small caps. These appear fine when viewing the exported PDF on a Mac however on a Windows computer some of the letters do not render properly.

This is how it appears on my computer and others running OSX.

[image: OSX]

I'm sorry this is the only image I have of the problem as it is on someone elses computer and apparently they don't know how to take a screenshot.

[image: Other computer]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for editing, I didn't have enough reputation to embed the images myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typeface has probably not been properly embedded in the PDF document. You don't notice on the computer creating the document, because the OS has access to the font.

You need to ensure, in the PDF export dialogs, that the typeface has been embedded. The wording varies, but the windows distiller printer driver has a check box, defaulted to checked, which says "rely on system fonts only." (edit: **note that "relying on system font only" is NOT what you want--you want the typefaces to be embedded in the document so that you do NOT have to rely on system fonts**)

The default is generally to NOT embed because they leave it up to you to lazily disregard typeface copyright. Note that many typeface licenses allow for embedding in cases where you are providing the work to e.g. a print provider.